# Converting playframework project to eclipse project when it contains errors

Tags: eclipse, playframework, playframework-2.2, typesafe-activator

So I am doing major change in a library(maven) which I have developed, and using it in one of the playframework project.

I have finished refactoring changes in maven artifact, published it to repository with new version.

Now I want to see where all this will give errors in play project, so that I can go and fix 100s of such errors. Ideally I would like to use eclipse or some IDE to report me all the errors, so that I can easily navigate and fix.

But problem is that eclipse doesn't know about new library version. To tell that to eclipse I have to upgrade library version in build.sbt, compile and re-create eclipse project. But since it contains many errors, I can not create eclipse project before fixing those.

Is there a way to visualize all those errors in eclipse or any IDE in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

You did not mentioned, if the play project is a maven project as well. I am working with play as a maven project, which is created [like this](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/05/create-maven-project-play-application.html). But I suppose, that with non-maven project the following works as well.

1. From the command line run:

   ```
   activator eclipse
   ```
2. In eclipse do 'refresh' to the project. Now you can see all the errors caused by the changes in your jars.

Comment: I was not aware that play project can be maven as well. in my case it is non-maven. Already tried running above command which fails due to compilation error.

$ ./activator eclipse
[error] 100 errors
[error] 1 warning
[error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] Could not create Eclipse project files:
[error] Error evaluating task 'dependencyClasspath': error

Comment: What with your eclipse project before changes? Did you update  the build.sbt with relevant dependencies? Clean of .ivy repository sometimes helps...

Comment: yes I did. If I don't update build.sbt, it would build successfully with older version of library. But I want see errors in eclipse due to changes in newer version of library.

Comment: I am doing the way I explained in the answer and this works. It is your challenge to figure out, where are you not doing the correct thing, My advice - start from the old dependencies; change them incrementally. Good luck !